# How to backup and restore containers odoo and postgres to other host machine?

Tags: docker, odoo

i have containers postgres and odoo in docker, docker is installed in ubuntu 18.04 machine.
I need to run containers odoo and postres in other machine , the probleme is  how to backup and restore images and containers postgres version:9.6 and odoo version:11 , in the other laptop ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to export container you should use `docker save` command:

```
docker save odoo | gzip > odoo.gz
docker save db | gzip > db.gz
```

where `odoo` and `db` are the **names** of **containers** that you want to export.

Then copy `odoo.gz` and `db.gz` files to the other laptop and import it using `docker load` command:

```
docker load < db.gz
docker load < odoo.gz
```

`docker load` will create an images named `odoo` and `db` which you should run to make containers based on them - use the same command as you used to run those containers on your initial laptop.

Please mind that `docker save` will export only `container` **not mounted volume** and (as you mentioned in the comment) you are using volume:

```
-v volume-pg:/var/lib/postgresql/
```

There is no easy way to export data from `docker volume` I am aware of, you can find suggested approach in official docker documentation for [volume management](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

You can find more details on `docker save` and `docker load` in official docker documentation:

[docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)

[docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)

PS. It looks like you are running independent docker containers instead of `docker-compose` which would manage the whole setup for you and is much better approach, you can find sample `docker-compose.yml` file on [docker hub page of odoo](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo). You can read about `docker-compose` [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). Please be aware that `docker-compose` will not solve your volume migration issue and you have to migrate `docker volumes` manually as I suggested above.

Comment: and for postgres container, i do like that ?

Comment: The same approach, just change the container name to your postgres container.

Comment: i have flow steps mentioned  above, but in the second laptop i have this error:
$ docker run -tid --network network99 --ip 172.99.0.92 -v  volume-pg:/var/lib/postgresql/  -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo --name pg99 pg99
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: hello @ahmedali I updated my answer to meet your needs, please read it carefully and migrate your containers and volumes (not only containers).

Comment: one more thing, you should not use `docker run -tid` just use `docker run -d` to run container in detached mode, when needed you can check logs using `docker logs -f odoo`

Comment: thank you so much @Imtx, i will do that but i don't use volume container, i use:

-v /volumes/docker/pg:/var/lib/postgresql/

Comment: the first command didn't work because i pass in argument a container, i should pass an image

Comment: You should use container name

Comment: thank you, i have solved this problem by runing command [ $ docker commit COUNTAINER_NAME CONTAINER_NAME ],  then execute commands above.  The problem that i didn't find modules installed in odoo at second laptop like i have in first laptop ?